# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Что (?) если все уже ушли?

Comment: Вероятно, "что" здесь является частицей, поэтому запятая необходима.

Comment: Жизнь слишком коротка, чтобы тратить её на разгадывание вербальных шарад.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что запятая нужна, хотя это и частица в  сочетании "а что если".Видимо, частицей местоимение стало после процесса "опрощения", сокращения фразы "что будет" или похожей. Поэтому и разногласия, одни не ставят запятую, потому что это всего частица, другие ставят, потому что было предложение.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_759

Answer (score 0):

Не надо. Не знаю как аргументировать, ибо просто не вижу оснований, по которым её тут модно поставить.

Что здесь не союзное и не вопросительное слово, скорее - частица.

Вот если бы было "что будет, если...". Тогда - другое дело.